# How to programmatically determine the currently active App in Android

Tags: android

Is there a way to find the app whose activity is currently active in android? Does android send a broadcast when a new app/activity is active?

Answer (score 5):

Call `ActivityManager.getRunningAppProcesses()`, then iterate through the `ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo` objects and look for the one(s) with `IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND`.

I'm not sure if there are situations (tablet? Laptop dock?) when you can have multiple foreground activities.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'd still like to know though if there is any broadcast sent when a new activity or package comes to foreground

Comment: Highly doubt it. Maybe an undocumented one, but you shouldn't use those anyway since they are bound to change.